# how to add more functions(label) to the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, model

I have a model in tensorflow for image recognition of objects. After training the model and saving it, I want to add more functions in it (more labels with new images). So I have to re-train the model myself or is there any other way to continue to train and develop this model?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible load the model with all of its weights and continue the training.

Running `model.fit(data)` on a loaded model will continue the training of `model` on the `data` dataset, from where it was loaded.

Comment: This data contains only new data or must include old data?

Comment: Either way works. For example, if you have 1k new data points and 10k old ones, continuing the training on the 11k data points won’t affect the weights that much. If you want your model to be fine tuned on the new data, you can only use the new data. It all depends on what your goal is.